# Convert xml to csv in Power shell

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

Hello I am new to Powershell, but I have looked all over for an answer to this question, how do I convert XML data to CSV data in powershell?

Here is my xml file:

```
<users>
     <user>
        <id>"data"</id>
        <name>"data"</name>
        <disabled>"data"</disabled>
        <title>"data"</title>
        <email>"data"</email>
        <role>
             <name>"data"</name>
        </role>
        <custom_fields_values>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60019</custom_field_id>
                <value>"data"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60021</custom_field_id>
                <value>"data"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60018</custom_field_id>
                <value>"data"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
        </custom_fields_values>
        <site>
            <name>"data"</name>
        </site>
    </user>
</users>
```

The fields that are multiple layers in the tree are the biggest pain. Here is the script I have come up with so far. I am able to get the basic fields such as name and email. I really need the fields that are labeled custom fields and their subsets.

```
#Converts the xml to a CSV file 
$samage_users.users.user | select-Object @(
@{l="Email";e={$_.email}},
@{l="Name";e={$_.name}},
@{l="ID";e={$_.ID}},
@{l="Phone";e={$_.phone}},
@{l="Site";e={$_.site.name}},
@{l="Reports_To";e={$_.reports_to.name}},
@{l="Reports_To_Email";e={$_.reports_to.email}})|
export-csv "Samanage_users.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
$page ++
start-sleep -s 10
}
While ($page -lt ($pages + 2))
}
Function NewUsers
{
foreach ($user in $new_user)
{
```

CSV output file should look something like this. (see attached)

[CSV Output File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAE5A.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Also show the desired output.

Comment: I have made corrections to my post.

Comment: Really? You want 'CUSTOM FIELD ID` followed by 'CUSTOM FIELD VALUE' for each of those, not just a column named '60019' with the appropriate value?

Comment: The program that I am working with makes you do that. You have to list out the id for each person to "activate" that field for that person. Then you list out the value for that field.

Comment: PowerShell will not play nice with that output because you have multiple columns with the same name. You'd have to do some shenanigans like assigning each custom field and its value their own property name, convert the object to CSV (not export), then skip the header row, and append that to your file as text.

Comment: In that case, I will try changing the column header to the field ID. If I did it that way, how could I alter my script to add those custom fields?

Comment: The open question here is - are all items in the input guaranteed to have the same number and the same kind of custom fields? CSV as an output format only works if that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my alteration of [TheMadTechnician's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661860/3439404), with necessary explaining comments:

```
$RObj = ForEach ($User in $samage_users.users.user) { 
  ### calculate basic properties - even those ones absent in XML
  $UObj = $user | Select-Object @(
    @{l="Email";e={$_.email}},
    @{l="Name";e={$_.name}},
    @{l="ID";e={$_.ID}},
    @{l="Phone";e={$_.phone}},
    @{l="Site";e={$_.site.name}},
    @{l="Rs_To";e={$_.reports_to.name}},   # "Rs_To"   cut "Reports_To"
    @{l="Rs_To_E";e={$_.reports_to.email}} # "Rs_To_E" cut "Reports_To_Email"
                                           # cuttings merely for better output readability
  )
  ### add user-dependent properties for each custom field 
    $User.custom_fields_values.custom_fields_value | 
      ForEach-Object {
        $UObj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name $_.custom_field_id -Value $_.value
      }
    $UObj     ### add current PSCustomObject to the `$RObj` array
}
### mutually arrange potentially missing user-dependent properties
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $RObj.Count; $i++ ) {
 for ($j = 0; $j -lt $RObj.Count; $j++ ) {
  if ( $i -ne $j ) {
   $RObj[$i] | ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Name } | 
    Where-Object { $_ -notin $RObj[$j].PSObject.Properties.Name } | 
     ForEach-Object { 
        $RObj[$j] | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_ -Value ''
     }
  }
 }
}
### $RObj | Export-Csv "Samanage_users.csv" -NoTypeInformation
### debugging output instead of `Export-Csv`
$RObj | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize
```

**Input** (modified original `XML`); entered separately to avoid vertical scrolling in above code:

```
$samage_users=[xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<users>
        <user>
        <id>"dI"</id>
        <name>"dN"</name>
        <disabled>"dD"</disabled>
        <title>"dT"</title>
        <email>"dE"</email>
        <role>
                <name>"dR"</name>
        </role>
        <custom_fields_values>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60044</custom_field_id>
                <value>"dC1"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60021</custom_field_id>
                <value>"dC2"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60018</custom_field_id>
                <value>"dC3"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
        </custom_fields_values>
        <site>
            <name>"dSi"</name>
        </site>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>"d2I"</id>
        <name>"d2N"</name>
        <disabled>"d2D"</disabled>
        <title>"d2T"</title>
        <email>"d2E"</email>
        <role>
                <name>"d2R"</name>
        </role>
        <Reports_To>
            <name>"d2RTn"</name>
            <email>"d2RTe"</email>
        </Reports_To>
        <custom_fields_values>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60021</custom_field_id>
                <value>"d2C1"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60018</custom_field_id>
                <value>"d2C2"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60034</custom_field_id>
                <value>"d2C3"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
        </custom_fields_values>
        <site>
            <name>"d2Si"</name>
        </site>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>"d3I"</id>
        <name>"d3N"</name>
        <disabled>"d3D"</disabled>
        <title>"d3T"</title>
        <email>"d3E"</email>
        <role>
                <name>"d3R"</name>
        </role>
        <custom_fields_values>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60055</custom_field_id>
                <value>"d3C1"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60066</custom_field_id>
                <value>"d3C2"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
        </custom_fields_values>
        <site>
            <name>"d3Si"</name>
        </site>
    </user>
</users>
'@
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell D:\PShell\SO\47660787.ps1

Email Name  ID    Phone Site   Rs_To   Rs_To_E 60044 60021  60018  60034  60055  60066 
----- ----  --    ----- ----   -----   ------- ----- -----  -----  -----  -----  ----- 
"dE"  "dN"  "dI"        "dSi"                  "dC1" "dC2"  "dC3"                      
"d2E" "d2N" "d2I"       "d2Si" "d2RTn" "d2RTe"       "d2C1" "d2C2" "d2C3"              
"d3E" "d3N" "d3I"       "d3Si"                                            "d3C1" "d3C2"
```

**Note** in regard of [Tomalak's useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660787/convert-xml-to-csv-in-power-shell#comment82282913_47661860) stating *that XML files should always be read using the `XmlDocument` object's `.Load()` method*.

```
###                   $samage_users defined as above i.e. a herestring cast to [xml] type
$xml = New-Object Xml
$xml.Load("Samanage_users.xml")            ### a file containing above herestring content
Compare-Object $samage_users.InnerXml $xml.InnerXml                     ### no difference
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to generate an object, similarly to how you are doing it now, but you would need to add properties to it for each custom field before outputting it. The only complication comes in if you have users with different custom fields. Since PowerShell won't output any properties that the first item in your array has you have to find all potential properties, and add them to the first object. This should do what you want I'm fairly sure. I've added a second user to the XML with a different custom field (replaced 60019 with 60034) to show the output.

```
[xml]$samage_users=@'
<users>
        <user>
        <id>"data"</id>
        <name>"data"</name>
        <disabled>"data"</disabled>
        <title>"data"</title>
        <email>"data"</email>
        <role>
                <name>"data"</name>
        </role>
        <custom_fields_values>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60019</custom_field_id>
                <value>"data"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60021</custom_field_id>
                <value>"data"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60018</custom_field_id>
                <value>"data"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
        </custom_fields_values>
        <site>
            <name>"data"</name>
        </site>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>"data2"</id>
        <name>"data2"</name>
        <disabled>"data2"</disabled>
        <title>"data2"</title>
        <email>"data2"</email>
        <role>
                <name>"data2"</name>
        </role>
        <custom_fields_values>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60021</custom_field_id>
                <value>"data2"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60018</custom_field_id>
                <value>"data2"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
            <custom_fields_value>
                <custom_field_id>60034</custom_field_id>
                <value>"data2"</value>
            </custom_fields_value>
        </custom_fields_values>
        <site>
            <name>"data2"</name>
        </site>
    </user>
</users>
'@

$Results = ForEach($User in $samage_users.users.user) {
    $UserObject = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        "Email" = $User.email
        "Name" = $User.name
        "ID" = $User.ID
        "Phone" = $User.phone
        "Site" = $User.site.name
        "Reports_To" = $User.reports_to.name
        "Reports_To_Email" = $User.reports_to.email
    }
    $User.custom_fields_values.custom_fields_value | ForEach {Add-Member -InputObject $UserObject -NotePropertyName $_.custom_field_id -NotePropertyValue $_.value}
    $UserObject
}
$Results | ForEach{ $_.PSObject.Properties.Name }| Select -Unique | Where{ $_ -notin $Results[0].PSObject.Properties.Name } | ForEach{ Add-Member -InputObject $Results[0] -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue ' ' }
$Results | FT *
```

The output of that is:

```
Email   Name    ID      Phone Site    Reports_To Reports_To_Email 60019  60021   60018   60034  
-----   ----    --      ----- ----    ---------- ---------------- -----  -----   -----   -----  
"data"  "data"  "data"        "data"                              "data" "data"  "data"         
"data2" "data2" "data2"       "data2"                                    "data2" "data2" "data2"
```

You could just as easily pipe `$Results` to `Export-Csv` if you need it output to a file.

Comment: It's worth noting that XML files should always be read using the `XmlDocument` object's `.Load()` method (as opposed to `Get-Content` plus explicit `[xml]` cast, which is often-used but wrong).

Comment: Add-Member : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'NotePropertyName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\dyl201\Desktop\uploadusers.ps1:50 char:117
+ ... -InputObject $UserObject -NotePropertyName $_.custom_field_id -NotePr ...
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Member], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCommand

Comment: That was the error that I got when I replaced my part of the script with everything starting at $results. It also asked for this: 
cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:

Comment: I assume you get that error because your actual XML doesn't have an array of objects with the `custom_field_id` and `value` properties. As for the export issue, just change that line to be `$Results | export-csv "Samanage_users.csv" -NoTypeInformation` to export the results to a file.

Comment: @Tomalak I don't see any functional difference in PowerShell. Do you have some point of reference to base that statement on? I would love to read up on the topic to understand why one way is wrong.

Comment: The point is simple - `Get-Content` requires prior knowledge and explicit declaration of the file encoding in order to not mess up the file (it will default to whatever is the default encoding on your machine, most likely Windows-1252). `XmlDocument.Load()` does - like any XML parser - full-fledged encoding check on the input file and adapts to every file encoding imaginable. Using `Get-Content` is less flexible due to the required hard-coding and will mess up your data without notice if you do it wrong. `XmlDocument.Load()` will always and transparently do the right thing.

Comment: `$xml = New-Object xml; $xml.Load($file)` is the way to go - not only in PowerShell, but in any situation that requires loading XML from a file.

Comment: I am still having some issues with updating my users. I believe the issue is later in my script. It is saying the argument is null or empty but I have something in the fields for each user. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you for the explanation, I appreciate it. I had not considered file encoding, and that's good to know that the XmlDocument.Load() will detect encoding and use the right one.

Comment: It's an extremely common mistake. Most people test with input that won't break even when read incorrectly. Take a UTF-8 file that by chance only contains the ASCII range. This will be byte-compatible to all the single-byte encodings out there. But as soon as the file producer starts to include extended characters and the consumer reads it as e.g. Windows-1252, things will fall apart. In the best case you get garbled text, or it will throw at runtime, because sth. like `<fóo>` is a perfectly legal XML tag name, but the respective Windows-1252 interpretation, `<fÃ³o>`, is not.